# Stop the system vibration on receive call in android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, vibration

i made a BroadcastReceiver that is listening for changes in the PHONE_STATE. in the onReceive method, i'd like to turn off the system vibrator. i tried different approaches, but non of them worked so far.

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager)ctx.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
systemVibration = audioManager.getVibrateSetting(AudioManager.VIBRATE_TYPE_RINGER);
audioManager.setVibrateSetting(AudioManager.VIBRATE_TYPE_RINGER, AudioManager.VIBRATE_SETTING_OFF);
```

or

```
Vibrator vib = (Vibrator)ctx.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
vib.cancel();
```

or

```
System.putInt(ctx.getContentResolver(), System.VIBRATE_ON, 0);
```

or all of them together.

the first approach with the AudioManager really changes the system setting for the vibration, but it does not affect the currently ongoing one.

any ideas?

Simon

Answer (score 1):

Stopping Vibration started by other process is not allowed in android now and thus this hack could stop Vibration or it will give you a feel that it has stopped vibration.

long timea = System.currentTimeMillis();
Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

while ((System.currentTimeMillis() - timea) < 15000) {
    v.vibrate(1);
    try {
        Thread.sleep(10);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
}

Answer (score 0):

Try this: (borrowed and modified from Android Source)

```
AudioManager am = Context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
boolean vibeInSilent = false;
int callsVibrateSetting = AudioManager.VIBRATE_SETTING_OFF;

Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), 
        Settings.System.VIBRATE_IN_SILENT,
        vibeInSilent ? 1 : 0);

//mAudioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE);
//or (not sure which one will work)
//mAudioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);

am.setVibrateSetting(AudioManager.VIBRATE_TYPE_RINGER,
        callsVibrateSetting);
```

Comment: i've seen that code snipped before. 2 problems here: 1. the phone is not in silent mode and 2. i can not find the value Settings.System.VIBRATE_IN_SILENT. in what version of android is that supposed to be? i'm using version 2.1 (7)

Comment: Settings.System.VIBRATE_IN_SILENT should exist in 2.1. It is just hidden in the documentation. Does the constant not work?

This should also work if it is not in silent-mode, but you will have to try uncommenting one of those two lines.

Comment: VIBRATE_IN_SILENT can not be resolved and the documentation sais that it is likely to be removed in a future release. i just used the string value "vibrate_in_silent" instead. this does indeed work, but switches the phone of course in silent mode which is not really my intention. the ringer mode should stay untouched, just the vibration should be switched off.

Comment: So you want it to ring, but not vibrate? If its just a matter of maintaining the option, just flip it back after a short timer.